# Ruby - Converting Multiple arrays to generate a Hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to convert 3 different arrays into a single Hash.

Here are the 3 arrays

```
@vehicle_numbers = ["Registration Number 1", "Registration Number 2", "Registration Number 1"]
@vehicle_colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
@allocated = [true, true, true]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is

```
{1=> ["Registration Number 1", "red", true], 2=> ["Registration Number 2", "blue", true]}
```

So far, I have achieved this

```
{1=> ["Registration Number 1", "red"], 2=>["Registration Number 2", "red"]}
```

I'm trying to add allocated key into the existing hash, but I'm not able to figure out, what is wrong with it.

```
@lines.each do |line|
      @method_name = line.split[0]
      if @method_name == "park"
        @vehicle_numbers << @vehicle_number = line.split[1]
        @vehicle_colors << @vehicle_color = line.split[2]
        @vehicle_info["#{@vehicle_number}"] = @vehicle_color
        # puts @vehicle_info["#{@vehicle_number}"] = @vehicle_color
      end
    end
    @slots = 1.step(@vehicle_numbers.count, 1).to_a
    @vehicle_info = Hash[(@slots).zip @vehicle_info ]
    @slots.each do |slot|
      puts "Allocated slot number: #{slot}"
    end
    puts @vehicle_info
```

Comment: "So far, I have achieved this" - it usually helps expose what exact problem you have if you post the _code_ that you used to achieve it.

Comment: You might want to look at inject, map and with_index

Comment: @Amadan Yup. I was in transit, hence could not paste the code at that point. I have updated what I have tried and it's messy.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line.

```
@vehicle_numbers.zip(@vehicle_colors, @allocated).each.with_index(1).to_h.invert
# => {1=>["Registration Number 1", "red", true], 2=>["Registration Number 2", "blue", true], 3=>["Registration Number 1", "green", true]}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[@vehicle_numbers, @vehicle_colors, @allocated].transpose.map.with_index { |a, i| [i + 1, a] }.to_h
```

Comment: `with_index` accepts an argument: `with_index(1) { |a, i| [i, a] }.to_h`.

Answer (score 2):

What about just iterating with index over `@vehicle_numbers` and get other values by that index?

```
@vehicle_numbers.map.with_index do |vehicle_number, index|
  [index + 1, [vehicle_number,  @vehicle_colors[index], @allocated[index]]]
end.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
(1..3).zip(
  [@vehicle_numbers, @vehicle_colors, @allocated].transpose
).to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. It works for me.

```
hash = (1..3).zip([@vehicle_numbers.map(&:to_s), @vehicle_colors.map(&:to_s), @allocated].transpose).to_h
```